# Trouble Mapping Private Shares From My Cloud EX2 Ultra

Tags: windows-10, network-attached-storage, windows-server-2019

Recently, one of my clients purchased a My Cloud EX2 Ultra unit and I am in the process of configuring both private and public shares.

[NAS Unit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psmxd.png)

I am able to access the public shares with no problem but it is asking me for the private share credentials of which I have configured on the unit:

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvhiF.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvhiF.png)

[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA5y6.png)

[Screenshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBhbZ.png)

Can anyone assist me in resolving the issue? I would greatly appreciate it!

I did follow the tutorial located on this forum but it did not help: https://community.wd.com/t/access-denied-enter-network-credentials/221404/4

Warm regards,

Michael.